# What does the phrase "keep fishing" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I found the phrase "keep fishing in this sentence: If you think I love you, keep fishing. What does the phrase "keep fishing" really mean?

Comment: Without additional context it's pure guesswork. Where did you find the phrase?

Comment: "Oh girl, when I'm in love with you
Keep fishin' if you feel it's true"

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. It could mean: 
If you think I love you, you've caught the wrong idea and should keep trying for a better thought. 
If you think I love you, keep trying and I might come around.
If you think I love you, try if you want to but it's hopeless (delivered with sarcasm).
I'd probably go for the first one.